# Send SMS using Windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a win form using which I can send the SMS to desired mobile number. I have tried different ways to send, But not succeeded in one, here are my efforts, which didn't worked. (These are all random numbers for posing)
First Try:

```
using SmsClient;
SendSms oSendSMS = new SendSms();
MessageBox.Show(oSendSMS.send("1234567890", "1111", "Hello", "1234567890"));
```

Second Try:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=" + uid + "&pwd=" + password + "&msg=" + message + "&phone=" + no + "&provider=way2sms");

            HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
            string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            respStreamReader.Close();
            myResp.Close();
```

Third Try:

```
using SMSClassLibrary;
    string status = "";
                CookieContainer cookie = Login.Connect("1234567890", "1111", out status);
                string[] siteParameters = Login.GetSiteParameters(cookie);
                MessageBox.Show(SendSMS.Send_Processing("1234567890", "jkdfhjnhsd", cookie, siteParameters));
```

Can any one please help in succeeding these efforts?

Comment: Please don't write off actual phone no's here publically. I suggest you to remove this and add dummy number e.g 123456

Comment: _"here are my efforts, which didn't worked"_ - **what** didn't work?

Comment: http://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: @CodeCaster You can see the code which I have been trying to send the SMS.

Comment: @Mohit yes, I can read. What happened when you issued that code? Did you get any errors? As it seems to be a GET API, can you issue the request from your browser? What happens then?

Answer (score 0):

See [the API's site](http://ubaid.tk/), which claims the "Way2SMS" provider (which you seem to use, according to your URL which ends with `&provider=way2sms`) does not work anymore for non-dedicated users.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly send an SMS over the internet, you need to use a provider with interconnects to the mobile networks and use what ever API they provide you with. Your second example looks like something along those lines.

Their are loads of providers, just search for bulk SMS or SMS API.

Comment: That page is a proxy service using third party providers, the one mentioned at the end of that URL (provider parameter) is now blocked according to the FAQ on that third parties site. I imagine that code was simply copied from somewhere without understanding it.